# Were there women teachers in Gurukulas?

Tags: women, guru, customs

Hindu mythology has mentions of the *Gurukula* system of education. I have heard how the Guru and the *Guru-Patni* (Guru's wife) lived with their students.

However, the Guru (teacher) is always a man. Is there any mention of any *Gurukulam* where the teacher is a woman?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Female teachers are there in hinduism. World-mother Jagadamba Parvati herself taught Banasur's daughter **Usha**. Parvati taught Usha dancing, singing, fighting and all Vedas also.

Another mother guru is *Gayatri Mata*, she is considered as mother of Vedas for all brahmins in hinduism.

In Gurukulam, female rishis were there. One of them is [Gargi Vachaknavi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gargi_Vachaknavi), she have also created some hymns in Upnishada.

Guru's wife is also a teacher in Gurukulam. One of them is Lopamudra, Wife of Sage Agastya.

There are many woman in hinduism who has guided someone in spiritual way, one of them is [Sarda Devi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarada_Devi).

The word Guru in Hinduism is referred to spiritual guider. One of such spiritual guider is [Muktabai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muktabai)

Comment: how and where do you people learn so much from?!?!?

Comment: From childhood only, we hear many stories from elders, rest some of us become curious and read Hindu scriptures, wikipedia, internet or any books...

Comment: Knowledge is a brick wall that you raise line by line forever.. keep reading.. keep searching.. keep sharing... It is good for the soul...

Comment: a few people i know have such detailed knowledge on Ramayan and Mahabharata, don't know how to use a computer. Just for fun sake, would you happen to know the First person to die in the battle of the Mahabharatha?? :)